# Meaning of "The experiment to be carried out was a success"

Tags: meaning, expressions

I can't quite get the meaning of this expression. "Was" is confusing me. Is it just a mistype of "with"?

> "The experiment to be carried out was a success."

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence is "The experiment was a success." Or: "The experiment succeeded."

The part of it which seems to be confusing you is "to be carried out." This phrase means *which was done*. It is superfluous. It is unnecessary. Of course the experiment was done; there is no need to say so. As it happens, emphasizing that it was *carried out* has accomplished only one thing: confusing you.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase " [Carry out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carry%20out)" means to continue to an end point. 
 The sentence probably means that

> The experiment was decided to be continued until it got a conclusion, and it turned out to be a successful one

Answer (score 1):

A potential source of confusion here is that the ellipsis is unpredictable before one sees the second part of the sentence.

> *The experiment to be carried out* was a success.
>
> *The experiment which was to be carried out* was a success (proved to have a successful outcome).

But

> *The experiment to be carried out* will hopefully be a success.
>
> *The experiment which is (going) to be carried out* will hopefully be a success.

(See at http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/hopefully for the licensing of the pragmatic-marker usage of 'hopefully'.)